# Linq How to Join and get 2 tables values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 2 tables and i want to match up 2 Id values.

First table

- Id - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
- DepartmentId  - 2, 4, 5, 2, 1

Second table

- Id- 1, 2, 10, 30, 40

I want to match up first table's Id's with second table's Id's so i can get DepartmentId values.

I need to get this virtual result:

- Id- 1, 2, 10, 30, 40
- DepartmentId -2, 4, null, null, null

Here is my code:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < model1.Count(); i++)
    { 
model1[i].DepartmentId= model2.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Id== model1[i].Id).DepartmentId; 
      }
```

I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   IYP.UserInterfaceLayer.dll but was not handled in user code

I think loop fails because of it can't find 10, 30, 40 Id values. If my Id values are same in 2 tables( Id = 1,2,3,4,5) loop works.

How can i do this with Linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically looking for Left Join in LINQ. Try this:-

```
 var query = from emp2 in Employee2
                        join emp1 in Employee1
                        on emp2.Id equals emp1.Id into allEmployees
                        from result in allEmployees.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            ID = emp2.Id,
                            DeptID = result == null ? "No Department" : result.DepartmentId.ToString()
                        };
```

Where I have used following types:-

```
          var Employee1 = new[]
            {
                new { Id = 1, DepartmentId  = 2 },
                new { Id = 2, DepartmentId  = 4 },
                new { Id = 3, DepartmentId  = 5 },
                new { Id = 4, DepartmentId  = 2 },
                new { Id = 5, DepartmentId  = 1 },
            };

        var Employee2 = new[] 
        {
            new { Id = 1 },
            new { Id = 2 },
            new { Id = 10 },
            new { Id = 30 },
            new { Id = 40 },
        };
```

Complete Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g9JkJH).

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that model1 and model2 are both IEnumerable. In that case the following should work.

```
var result = from x in model2
select
   new Model1Type {DepartamentId = x,
Value=
model1.FirstOrDefault(y=>y.DepartamentId==x)
.Select(y=>y.Value)};
```

This is called Lamq :D 
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the *Join* LINQ extension method. In the form of query syntax (which I believe is more readable for this case) it will look like:

```
var matchedValues =
    from second in model2
    join first in model1
        on second.Id equals first.Id
        into temp
    from tempFirst in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select
        new 
        {
            second.Id,
            DepartmentId = tempFirst == null ? null : tempFirst.DepartmentId
        };
```

You join on the *Id* property and for any value you don't find in the *model1*, you use a default (*DefaultIfEmpty* call). Then you choose the resulting *DepartmentId* based on the join result.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
List<long> idlist=model2.tolist().select(t=>t.Id);
List<long> depIdList=model1.where(t=>idlist.contains(t.id)).toList();
```